# How do you handle "support" on your products (inhouse)

Tags: web-development, php

Do you have any kind of update process?

Let's assume you are an "in-house" development shop for php inside your company. You are creating an bunch of applications for other units.

Do you have something like "Support ends in 2 years" ? What happens if you develop an app for php 5.3, and this app can't run with php "6", or another framework you use will no longer be maintained?

Would love to hear some ideas :-)

Comment: Try programmers.se?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Support should be no different in-house**.

I've always felt users in an organization should be treated like customers. You must **delight** them. You will sleep well every night.

The problem you specifically address should be discussed with the business owner that ordered the application.

It's the same process. A department need an application, they write the specifications, you estimate it, etc.

Just replace **customer** with **user**.

Comment: Yes! I'm always delighted when a co-worker bends over backwards to help me with some internal tool they created. So I try to do the same with my tools.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the reasons for which it is being built in house. Most of the time it is to save money and utilize existing talent. Usually if it is built in house, it stays in house, and it is supported in house until it is rebuilt (again in house). It would be supported indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You must define clearly what your product requires to work. Otherwise you're cheating your customers. That is, if your product works with PHP 5.3, then make it clear that it requires PHP 5.3.
2. As a good salesman, you of course won't abandon your customers after you've sold the first version to them. Instead, when PHP 6 becomes current, you'll *sell an upgrade* to your existing customers so that they can continue using your product with a little extra investment.

It's important to support your customers as well as possible, but it's also important to get paid for it.

Comment: Hi Joonas, thx for your comment. We only develop if we get an order, we are talking about inhouse (there is only an budget if an inhouse customer asks for an tool) we cant develop "pro-active.."

Comment: Oops, completely ignored the "inhouse". Sorry!-)